# Do I have to await .vm.$emit()?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have a Vue 3 application and use vue-test-utils for testing.

I also use web components. One of the components is an input element that implements an `inputChanged` event that is triggered in case the input is changed.

Lets say the `inputChanged` event leads to data being rendered in the template:

Template:

```
...
<InputWebComponent
    id="email-input"
    label="Email"
    :value="currentEmail"
    @inputChanged="onEmailChanged"/>
...
```

Code:

```
onEmailChanged(event: CustomEvent<string>) {
    this.currentEmail = event.detail;
}
```

When it comes to testing such an event, I found examples where people use the following in the test:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(ComponentToBeTested, { props: ... });
// emitting the event
await wrapper.findComponent(InputWebComponent).vm.$emit('inputChanged', { detail: 'some@mail.com' });
// test if something happened
...
```

Here is my question:
The web component does not return a promise when emitting `inputChanged`. And the examples I found in the [documentation](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/emitted.html) (note that the examples have changed a little for the Vue 3 documentation and for some reason, do no longer use .vm.$emit()) there is no `await` added before emitting.
Also the test works without the `await` in my code.

Do I have to `await` an event emitted in the test via `.vm.$emit()`?

Comment: Emitting an event does not call the subscribers before it returns - event listeners will be called inside the next micro-task/event loop cycle. Therefore you do not have to `await`.